# Mousedown won't change property and run function on range sliders

Tags: javascript, range, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

I've got two sets of range sliders on a video file that need some fine-tuning.

Clicking and dragging the slider will adjust the settings. But **clicking without dragging** will not change the settings, it will only move the slider.

I need the slider to adjust the settings **when any point is clicked within the range**. In the words, if the range is currently set to the far right and I click the far left, I'd like it to change settings.

I tested it and noticed that the line with the comment doesn't seem to activate the function *handleRangeUpdate*.

```
const ranges = player.querySelectorAll(".player__slider");
let isDragging = false;

function handleRangeUpdate() {
  if (!isDragging) return;
  console.log(`${this.name}: ${this.value}`);
  video[this.name] = this.value;
}

ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener("mousemove", handleRangeUpdate));
ranges.forEach(range =>
  range.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    isDragging = true;
    handleRangeUpdate; // This doesn't seem to function
  })
);
ranges.forEach(range =>
  range.addEventListener("mouseup", () => (isDragging = false))
);
```

You can find all my code on: [My Github Repo](https://github.com/damsalem/JavaScript-30-Day-Challenge/tree/master/11%20-%20Custom%20Video%20Player)

Comment: try actually calling it `handleRangeUpdate();`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. It does trigger a console.log, but of "undefined"